# RecyclerView item onClick - Visual feedback

Tags: android, user-interface, touch, android-recyclerview, android-cardview

I have a `RecyclerView` with `CardView` items.

On `LongClick` i'm showing a `FAB` and I'd also like to put some kind of effect around the selected `cardview` item. I tried setActivated, setHovered, setEnabled to achieve SOME KIND of effect but still no success.

**EDIT:**

Then I saw this post on the [google website](https://www.google.com/design/spec/animation/responsive-interaction.html#responsive-interaction-radial-action) and apparently they are using `ViewPropertyAnimator` class to animate the `Card View`. Does anyone have an example implementation of that effect because I don't have a clue how to animate things.

For now, that's what I'm using in my `onLongPress` method but it's not animated:

```
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 21) {
                        child.setTranslationZ(5f);
                        child.setElevation(3f);
                        child.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.tealfifty));
                    }
```

I implemented a `Touch listener` in the following way:

```
class RecyclerTouchListener implements RecyclerView.OnItemTouchListener {
    private GestureDetector gestureDetector;
    private ClickListener clickListener;

    public RecyclerTouchListener(Context context, final RecyclerView recyclerView, final ClickListener clickListener) {
        this.clickListener = clickListener;
        gestureDetector = new GestureDetector(context, new GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onSingleTapUp(MotionEvent e) {
                return true;
            }

            @Override
            public void onLongPress(MotionEvent e) {
                View child = recyclerView.findChildViewUnder(e.getX(), e.getY());
                if (child != null && clickListener != null) {
                    clickListener.onLongClick(child, recyclerView.getChildAdapterPosition(child));
                    //child.setEnabled(false); DO LOGIC HERE?
                }
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(RecyclerView rv, MotionEvent e) {
        View child = rv.findChildViewUnder(e.getX(), e.getY());
        if (child != null && gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(e)) {
            clickListener.onClick(child, rv.getChildAdapterPosition(child));
        }
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public void onTouchEvent(RecyclerView rv, MotionEvent e) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(boolean disallowIntercept) {

    }
}

public interface ClickListener {
    void onClick(View v, int position);

    void onLongClick(View v, int position);
}
```

Comment: and the reason behind this downvote?

Comment: I think its because we still don't know what u want, a simple hover on `Card`?

Comment: Well i clearly said what I want in my last sentences "I guess the desired effect would be some kind of glow or extra elevation...?" This means I'd like to inform the user which child is selected clearly and I'd like someone to suggest what I could do. I guessed maybe some kind of glow (border) or extra elevation.